# Mapping Keyboard buttons to a usb device

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, remapping, input-device

Hey, I was wondering if it is possible in Windows to run a program, that will map lets say the "r" button to something like an xbox controller's trigger or the mouse's wheel?

Answer (score 2):

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) would be what you're looking for. It lets you create hotkeys for joysticks and mouse.

[Autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml) is an alternative to AHK and also does a great job at creating custom hotkeys.

Comment: I suggest AutoHotkey , Autoit is seen as virus by many antivirus programs :)

Comment: @nXqd I just did a quick search and it seems that it is being flagged as a virus because of its compressor (upx.exe), only Avast flags it as a threat.

Thanks for the information though, never knew about it